# Ruby - No such file or directory in system32

Tags: ruby, windows, system32

I'm trying to execute a ruby script in C:\Windows\System32\ but the ruby interpreter throws a LoadError when I try to run it.

Anyone had this happen?

[image]

Comment: Please provide information about how you are executing script.

Comment: @MarsRover: I'm sorry, I don't follow. I execute the script by running `ruby .\rest.rb` in PowerShell like in the image attached if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Shouldn't be `ruby rest.rb`?

Comment: @esimov, That is how PowerShell autocompletes paths. dot here is the current path so `.\rest.rb` translates to "The file named `rest.rb` in the current folder".

Comment: where you kept your script? show us the content of your `.rb` file.

Comment: Did you try to execute the script in another folder or does it happen only in this specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

i am not used to ruby but as far as cmd is concerned try `ruby rest.rb`

Comment: That's how Powershell autocompletes paths. . (dot) being the current path, but I tried it to make sure and it throws the same error.

Comment: Nope, that link is referring to installing RubyGems on cygwin, not problems running ruby scripts.

Comment: Are you using RGLoader for Ruby gem. If yes then check the gem version and whether you have all the required files or not.